# Smtp emails sending not working?

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp

i used SMTP server to send emails.i used creatuserwizard in asp to create a registration form .
This is aspx file.

```
 <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="userwizard" ContinueDestinationPageUrl="~/secretfiles/secret.aspx" runat="server" >
  <MailDefinition BodyFileName="register.txt" Subject="Registration Confirmation" From="amrit.enest@gmail.com" />
  </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

This is my web.config file.

```
<mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory" from="amrit.enest@gmail.com">
    <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\Users\eNest-25\Desktop\emails"/>
    </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
```

The .eml files are being generate in pickup-directory location with the information about email but user yet didn't receive it not it is being shown in sent mails of sender's email id.
Why?

I didn't provide password of email which is being used to send emails anywhere.i doubt how can smtp can send mails without knowing the password of sending email

Please help

Comment: not any execption.
.eml file has been generated even.

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong but doesn't specifying the pickup directory delivery method prevent actual sending of the email files? I think your delivery method tells the server to only place the email in the specified directory, that is to say, to avoid actually sending them..

I think you need to specify deliveryMethod="Network" for it to actually send the email.

Update: Example web.config configuration:

```
<smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="someaddress@classifiedspak.com">
    <network
    host="smtp.yourmailserver.com"
    userName="user@yourmailserver.com"
    password="*************"
    port="25"
    enableSsl="true" />
</smtp>
```

Username and password are only needed if your server requires authentication. I'm assuming you want ssl encryption to the server.

Comment: I agree with you.There should be some method further which will send mails(using .eml files in pickup directory) .but i don't know how to do it.

Please Help if you know.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. Either you want the email messages to be sent to the recipient or you want the server to put the email in the pickup directory (e.g. for development purposes, you only want to see the email being generated correctly)..

Either you specify Network with sends the email to the recipient or you direct it to the pickup directory. I don't think the options allow for both without some third party component (nor can I see why you'd want to)..

Comment: i want the emails messages to be sent to the recipient ,not only to store them to pickup directory.
Where to provide settings for that ?
Thanks for reply.

Comment: I added an example configuration in my answer.